# Connect to a named pipe in the same network without Administrator rights

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi

I created a named pipe server and granted full access rights to Everyone.
I tried to connect to the named pipe server from different machine on the same network but I get an error says the login failed - ERROR_LOGON_FAILURE.

I read about NullSessionPipes and I compiled the example from MSDN. However, I need an administration right to register the NullSessionPipe in the registry which I'm trying to avoid.

How does CreateFile actually do the login to the remote named pipe? Do I need to run my client in a specific context to make this works? (e.g Guest).

server code:

```
DWORD dwRes, dwDisposition;
PSID pEveryoneSID = NULL, pAdminSID = NULL;
PACL pACL = NULL;
PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR pSD = NULL;
EXPLICIT_ACCESS ea[2];
SID_IDENTIFIER_AUTHORITY SIDAuthWorld =
    SECURITY_WORLD_SID_AUTHORITY;
SID_IDENTIFIER_AUTHORITY SIDAuthNT = SECURITY_NT_AUTHORITY;
SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa;
LONG lRes;
HKEY hkSub = NULL;

// Create a well-known SID for the Everyone group.
if (!AllocateAndInitializeSid(&SIDAuthWorld, 1,
    SECURITY_WORLD_RID,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    &pEveryoneSID))
{
    return false;

}

// Initialize an EXPLICIT_ACCESS structure for an ACE.
// The ACE will allow Everyone read access to the key.
ZeroMemory(&ea, 1 * sizeof(EXPLICIT_ACCESS));
ea[0].grfAccessPermissions = 0xFFFFFFFF;
ea[0].grfAccessMode = SET_ACCESS;
ea[0].grfInheritance = NO_INHERITANCE;
ea[0].Trustee.TrusteeForm = TRUSTEE_IS_SID;
ea[0].Trustee.TrusteeType = TRUSTEE_IS_WELL_KNOWN_GROUP;
ea[0].Trustee.ptstrName = (LPTSTR)pEveryoneSID;

// Create a new ACL that contains the new ACEs.
dwRes = SetEntriesInAcl(1, ea, NULL, &pACL);
if (ERROR_SUCCESS != dwRes)
{
    return false;
}

// Initialize a security descriptor.  
pSD = (PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR)LocalAlloc(LPTR,
    SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR_MIN_LENGTH);
if (NULL == pSD)
{
    return false;

}

if (!InitializeSecurityDescriptor(pSD,
    SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR_REVISION))
{
    return false;
}

// Add the ACL to the security descriptor. 
if (!SetSecurityDescriptorDacl(pSD,
    TRUE,     // bDaclPresent flag   
    pACL,
    FALSE))   // not a default DACL 
{
    return false;
}

// Initialize a security attributes structure.
sa.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES);
sa.lpSecurityDescriptor = pSD;
sa.bInheritHandle = FALSE;

// create named pipe
auto NamedPipe = CreateNamedPipeA(namedPipeName,
                                    PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX,
                                    PIPE_TYPE_MESSAGE | PIPE_READMODE_MESSAGE | PIPE_NOWAIT | PIPE_ACCEPT_REMOTE_CLIENTS,
                                    PIPE_UNLIMITED_INSTANCES,
                                    NAMED_PIPE_SIZE,
                                    NAMED_PIPE_SIZE,
                                    NMPWAIT_USE_DEFAULT_WAIT, 
                                    &sa);
```

Comment: Can you provide some code and specifics about the failure?

Comment: @Hogstrom edited

Comment: everyone != anonymous - this is different sid. you nothing grant to anonymous. also better in this case simply set DACL to 0

Comment: @RbMm same error.

Comment: this error was before checking pipe at all. you can even set not existing name - you got the same error - `STATUS_LOGON_TYPE_NOT_GRANTED`

Comment: and look like you not call `WNetAddConnection2W` from client. and need add `WinUntrustedLabelSid` to pipe sacl

Comment: `[Nt]CreateFile` itself doesn't handle this. The create I/O request for the UNC path goes through MUP to the SMB redirector, mrxsmb[20].sys, which opens a session to the server for the IPC$ (named pipe) share.

Answer (score 3):

how do this task described in [How to create an anonymous pipe that gives access to everyone](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/813414/how-to-create-an-anonymous-pipe-that-gives-access-to-everyone)

the error `ERROR_LOGON_FAILURE` say that client code not makes a connection to a network resource. really need call [`WNetAddConnection2`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winnetwk/nf-winnetwk-wnetaddconnection2w) (or analog api before call `CreateFile` on remote pipe)

> The client opens the pipe with a call to the `CreateFile` function. If
>   an error occurs, the client checks if it is a logon failure error, an
>   access denied error, or a bad password error. If an error occurs,
>   perform an anonymous logon by calling the `WNetAddConnection2` function
>   and passing an empty string as user name and password. When the null
>   session is established, the client calls the `CreateFile` function
>   again.

so client code must look like:

```
    NETRESOURCE nr = {};
    nr.dwUsage = RESOURCEUSAGE_CONNECTABLE|RESOURCEUSAGE_CONTAINER;
    nr.lpRemoteName = L"\\\\server\\IPC$";

    WNetAddConnection2W(&nr, L"", L"",0);

    HANDLE hFile = CreateFileW(L"\\\\?\\UNC\\server\\PIPE\\MyPipe",
        FILE_GENERIC_READ|FILE_GENERIC_WRITE, 
        0, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0);
```

from server side need not only set 0 in place *DACL* (this allow any access) or add allowed *ACE* for [*WinAnonymousSid*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winnt/ne-winnt-well_known_sid_type) (this is != *WinWorldSid* aka *everyone*) but also set untrusted mandatory label. this is slipped in code example, because i think code yet pre vista.

```
    SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR sd;
    BOOL fOk = InitializeSecurityDescriptor(&sd, SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR_REVISION) &&
        SetSecurityDescriptorDacl(&sd, TRUE, 0, FALSE);

    if (fOk)
    {
        RTL_OSVERSIONINFOW ovi = { sizeof(ovi) };
        if (0 > RtlGetVersion(&ovi))
        {
            fOk = FALSE;
        }
        else
        {
            if (ovi.dwMajorVersion > 5)
            {
                fOk = FALSE;
                ULONG cb = GetSidLengthRequired(1);
                PSID UntrustedLabelSid = alloca(cb);
                if (CreateWellKnownSid(WinUntrustedLabelSid, 0, UntrustedLabelSid, &cb))
                {
                    PACL Sacl = (PACL)alloca(cb += sizeof(ACL) + sizeof(ACE_HEADER) + sizeof(ACCESS_MASK));
                    fOk = InitializeAcl(Sacl, cb, ACL_REVISION) &&
                        AddMandatoryAce(Sacl, ACL_REVISION, 0, SYSTEM_MANDATORY_LABEL_NO_WRITE_UP, UntrustedLabelSid) &&
                        SetSecurityDescriptorSacl(&sd, TRUE, Sacl, FALSE);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```